# Determining Average buying cycle for customer in R

Tags: r, date

I am new to R programming.
I have invoice details of each customer, with dates and would like to know average buying cycle for each customer. Data is like:

```
----------------------------
|Cust_no |Invoice_no | Date|
----------------------------

| C001   |    W012    | 4/1/2015 
-----------------------------------
| C001  |  W234   |   4/11/2015
-----------------------------------
|C001 |    W321   |     5/1/2015
-----------------------------------
|C002   | W131    |   4/1/2015
----------------------------------
|C002  |  W245    |   4/13/2015
----------------------------------
|C003  |  W047    |   3/18/2015
----------------------------------
```

so for each customer, the code should sum the difference between consecutive dates and divide it by (n-1). n= no. of transactions for each customer. if there is only one transaction present, then I would like to output a default no. (say 45 days)

next after getting avg. buying cycle (C) for each customer, I would like like to see which customer buying cycle is approaching(to send notification)
example:
flag 'buying period near' as '1' if:
(C-2)*n <= days passed since last invoice <= (C+2)*n
n=1,2,3...

suppose today is 15 may 2015, then we will have following output.

Expected output
For customer C001, average buying cycle would be = (10+20)/(3-1)= 15 days.
For customer C002, average buying cycle would be = (10)/(2-1)= 10 days
For customer C003, 45 days since only one transaction, given default value of 45.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Cust_no |Buying_cycle|last_invoice_date|time_since_last_inv|buy_perd_near
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

| C001  |    15    | 5/1/2015 |14 | 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| C002  |  12  |   4/13/2015 |32 | 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| C003  |    45   |  3/18/2015 |68 | 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am facing challenge to find avg. buying period. Once I can get the avg. buying period, I can apply logic to find whether buying period is near or not.

Note: The raw data will not be sorted by customer or ascending/descending dates.

{

```
structure(list(cust_no = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("c001", 
"c002", "c003"), class = "factor"), inv_no = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 5L), .Label = c("w015", "w087", "w167", "w231", 
"w234", "w456"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
5L, 1L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("2015-4-1", "2015-4-11", "2015-4-13", 
"2015-4-17", "2015-5-1"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("cust_no", 
"inv_no", "date"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide your data in a format that's easily imported by others and the expected output. Some effort of your own in solving your issue is appreciated. Here is more info on creating a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: start here [http://www.statmethods.net/] in the Import Data

Comment: Hi, @Dipesh. Have you successfully gotten your data into a data.frame or even a matrix or even a series of vectors? I see you working very hard to make some data, but I don't think that is your actual data. Before you worry about your average buying period calculation we need to get your data sorted. If you do have the data, can you just paste it into the page and we can format it for you from there.

Answer (score -1):

As you do not have reproducible data, I will be posting steps to achive the result you desire and not the whole code

You can convert your dates to the day number as:

```
library(lubridate)
x <- c("02/01/2000", "20/02/2000", "12/12/2000", "13/01/2001")
date <- dmy(x)
```

Now use `diff` on the sorted vector from base R to get difference between consecutive values as:

```
diff(date)
```

And find the average of it.

Comment: buying cycle=sum(diff(date))/length(date)-1.    how do I do it for each customer. some looping would be required I guess.

Comment: @Dipesh please look for `apply`, `sappy`, `lapply`